# Regex - Let any character that is not ' or ; through

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions and I cannot find a way to make it so that I let any character (letter, number, space, _, or special character such as é, à and so on) but I do NOT let anything through that could lead to MySQL injection, such as ' or ;.  Is there a way to do that?

I tried:

```
if (preg_match("/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]$/", $name)) {
    echo "YAY IT WORKED!";
}
```

but alas YAY IT WORKED was not echo'd that day

Comment: Preventing SQL injection using regular expressions?  Interesting.

Comment: "I am trying to learn regular expressions" Try harder.

Comment: Reject!!! How are you going to store `McDonald's` or any name with `'` in it?

Comment: **You can't prevent SQL injection by disallowing the use of certain characters.** Use parameterized queries — that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid the SQL injection.

> If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur

How to use

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
```

Comment: Okay, now how can I use that in a foreach loop? like I have this: `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM champs WHERE id = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $champId); foreach($stmt->execute() as $row) { }` and I get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/70/11524070/html/livestats.php on line 100`

Comment: $stmt->execute() returns boolean and then use $stmt->fetchAll()

Comment: @NambiNarayanan, please stop using `code formatting` for `emphasis`.  It's *code* formatting.  For code.  Not for emphasis.

Comment: @Charles Thanks Here after i have this practice

Answer (score 3):

You probably want PDO, but here:

```
$name = mysqli_reql_escape_string($mysqli_connection, $name);
```

Don't reject the input, just escape it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you do want to use prepare statements. However, you presumably still want to learn regexes for other things. Right now your regex looks like this: "beginning of input, a character which is not 0-9, a character which is A-z, 0-9, or _, then end of input." If you want a regex which just tells you whether there is a character in the string other than ', ", or ;, simply do: `/[^'";]/`. Also note, I'm not sure if A-z works in PHP; I wouldn't recommend it regardless, since I think it doesn't work other places.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that this is not the best method of SQL injection protection.  In terms of learning regex, however, you can convert a string: `'foo'bar;` into `foobar` with the following function:

```
function sanitize($input="'foo'bar;"){
    $output=preg_split("('|;)",$input);
    $output=implode("",$output);
    return $output;
}
```

The regex in `preg_split` uses `|` as the OR operator so you can list as many characters as you want there.  `preg_split` splits the input string into an array, then `implode` combines the array back into a string, without any of the regex-matched characters.